# Extra white space on the left and lost part on the right with html2canvas

Tags: html2canvas

The width of extra and lost parts seems always 8px when I tried to download the image via html2canvas.

```
html2canvas(elementRef.nativeElement).then((canvas) => {
      let link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      link.download = fileName;
      document.body.appendChild(link);
      link.click();
    });
```

[image: sample image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved all possible problems as follows..

```
html2canvas(element , {
        scrollX: -window.scrollX,
        scrollY: -window.scrollY,
        windowWidth: document.documentElement.offsetWidth,
        windowHeight: document.documentElement.offsetHeight
})
```